# Explorer Integration

Tags: webdav, explorer, windows-explorer

I would like to show my own list of files & folders in explorer. For eg, if I have a empty folder, say 'D:/Store' , then when click on the particular folder from explorer, I would like to send the list of files/folders to be listed from my application (by querying internal db / metadata). Explorer, should use those lists and list them as a normal file folder list (virtual file folder list). Then again, further navigation should do happened by querying my internal database. Similarly, if they try to open a file, I will send the content of the particular file from my application, and explorer should show it.

Please let me know, whether it is possible ?

If not, 
i) whether I have to create my own explorer windows to achieve this.
ii)  Or WebDAV will help me to achieve my requirement.

If so, which language will be opt for that. I am familiar with c/c++. Let me know, if some other languages / tools I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like the [Shell Storage example](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/shellapplication)?

Comment: From the above examples, I have tried ExplorerBrowserCustomContents project, seems they open a custom window to list the entries. I would like to know, can we list our custom entries in the explorer. ie, virtual listing of files & folders within our custom folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what webdav is for. The protocol is conceptually simple so you could in theory implement your own server-side protocol handling, but in practise there are a lot of per client idiosyncrasies to be handled, so you're better off using a library.

So you'll need to integrate your database with a webdav server library. For example http://milton.io (my project) is a java library for this purpose. Using it is simple, there are lots of examples, many people get a simple implementation running with windows in a few hours. Milton is a very active project and there is good support (mostly from me!)

If you prefer to use php the SabreDav library is very good and actively maintained.

Comment: And here's a youtube showing an example in action, gives you an idea of what can be achieved - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_fz4HdygQs